# CSS display:none won't hide YouTube Embed (no jQuery)

Tags: css, wordpress, youtube

I'm having difficulties getting an embedded YouTube video to not show on my site. The thing is there are two of the same embedded videos on the page and I would like to hide one.

There are 2 because one is generated by the wordpress theme (I have to paste the embed code somewhere in the theme settings) while the other is the direct youtube link pasted into the editor, the sole purpose being to auto generate featured image from the video thumbnail.

I would like to hide the second one, preferrably. I know it can easily be deleted by deleting the YouTUbe link in the text editor after publishing.  But I want it to not to have to show at all at the time the page is initially published.

In attempt to hide any of the 2 videos, I have tried this CSS and it doesn't seem to work

```
div.entry-video-wrapper {display:none !important;}
div.entry-video iframe {display:none !important;}
div.fluid-with-video-wrapper {visibility:hidden !important;}
```

Is there anything I might be doing wrong?

Here's the sample page I'm working on http://wazobiajournal.tv/gallery/game-of-thrones-season-4-fire-and-ice-foreshadowing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide first video then use:

```
.entry-video .fluid-width-video-wrapper{
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide second video then use:

```
.embed-youtube .fluid-width-video-wrapper{
    display: none;
}
```

Although your code is also working and it seems that you have to clear cache to see it in action.

**Note:** Avoid using `!important`, it is not a good practice.

Comment: Yeah apparently,I should have cleared the cache. Silly me. It works now thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean cache maybe. I'm just trying to add display: none; for .entry-video-wrapper in CSS and it's work for me:

```
.entry-video-wrapper {
    margin: 0 -30px;
    display: none;
}
```